# Pylons and AuthKit OpenID problem

Tags: python, openid, pylons, authkit

I have troubles setting up the support for openID authentication, using authkit and pylons.
I set up everything as described in the [cookbook](http://docs.pythonweb.org/display/authkitcookbook/OpenID+Passurl), but still get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/authkit/authenticate/open_id.py", line 480, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/authkit/authenticate/open_id.py", line 218, in __call__
    self.session_middleware
AuthKitConfigError: The session middleware 'beaker.session' is not present. Have you set up the session middleware?
```

(The full traceback is quite uninformative, just a chain of middleware calls)

My config is the following:

```
authkit.setup.method = openid, cookie
# TODO authkit.openid.template.file =
authkit.cookie.params.httponly = true


authkit.openid.store.type = file
authkit.openid.store.config = %(here)s/data
authkit.openid.session.middleware = beaker.session
authkit.openid.session.key = authkit_openid
authkit.openid.baseurl = http://mysite.moc
authkit.openid.path.signedin = /main/cabinet
authkit.openid.authenticate.user.encrypt = authkit.users:md5
```

The beaker middleware is definitely loaded, here is my make_app function (yes, the pylons version check is true):

```
|       # Configure the Pylons environment
|       load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
|   
|       # The Pylons WSGI app
|       app = PylonsApp()
|       app = UserMiddleware(app)
|   
|       if pylons.__version__ >= "0.9.7":
|-          from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
||          from routes.middleware import RoutesMiddleware
||          app = RoutesMiddleware(app, config['routes.map'])
||          app = SessionMiddleware(app, app_conf)
|   
|   
|       if asbool(full_stack):                                                                                                                               
|           # Handle Python exceptions
|   
|-          app = authkit.authenticate.middleware(app, app_conf)
||          # Display error documents for 401, 403, 404 status codes (and
||          # 500 when debug is disabled)
||          if pylons.__version__ >= "0.9.7":
||-             app = ErrorHandler(app, global_conf,
23-                            **config['pylons.errorware'])
|||             from pylons.middleware import StatusCodeRedirect
|||             if asbool(config['debug']):
23-                 app = StatusCodeRedirect(app)
|||             else:
23-                 app = StatusCodeRedirect(app, [401, 403, 404, 500])
||          else:
||-             app = ErrorHandler(app, global_conf, error_template = error_template,
23-                            **config['pylons.errorware'])
|||             app = ErrorDocuments(app, global_conf, mapper=error_mapper, **app_conf)
|   
|       # Establish the Registry for this application
|       app = RegistryManager(app)
|   
|       # Static files
|       javascripts_app = StaticJavascripts()
|       static_app = StaticURLParser(config['pylons.paths']['static_files'])
|       app = Cascade([static_app, javascripts_app, app])
|       return app
```

Does anyone have any idea, what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this line in your middleware.py:

```
app = authkit.authenticate.middleware(app, app_conf)
```

And move it immediately below this line:

```
app = PylonsApp()
```